# How do next track AVPlayer

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift3, avplayer

I tried for a few days to make a button which includes the next song but I can not
Here is my question
How to put the next екфсл at the click of a button with avPlayer

it is my code

```
class ViewControllerAudioDetail: UIViewController {


var avPlayer:AVQueuePlayer?
var status = false
fileprivate let seekDuration: Float64 = 10
fileprivate let seekDurationThirty: Float64 = 30

var mod = [Modal]()



@IBOutlet weak var ImageView: UIImageView!

@IBOutlet weak var startTime: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var endTime: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var sliderSong: UISlider!
@IBOutlet weak var name: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var Volume: UISlider!
@IBOutlet weak var iconChange: UIButton!


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    Volume.setThumbImage(UIImage(named:"Play.png"), for: .normal)
    sliderSong.minimumValue = 0
    sliderSong.maximumValue = 1

    name.text = mod[thisSong].AudioName
    ImageView.image = mod[0].ImageViewAudio


    let url = URL(string: mod[thisSong].UrlName!)
    let playerItem = AVPlayerItem(url: url!)
    avPlayer = AVQueuePlayer(playerItem:playerItem)


    let _ = avPlayer!.addPeriodicTimeObserver(forInterval: CMTime(seconds: 1, preferredTimescale: CMTimeScale(NSEC_PER_SEC)), queue: DispatchQueue.main) { [weak self] (time) in

        let duration = CMTimeGetSeconds((self?.avPlayer!.currentItem!.asset.duration)!)
        self?.sliderSong.value = Float(CMTimeGetSeconds(time)) / Float(duration)

    }


    let duration = CMTimeGetSeconds(avPlayer!.currentItem!.asset.duration)
    let minutesTextOut = Int(duration) / 60 % 60
    let secondsTextOut = Int(duration) % 60
    let strDuration = String(format:"%02d:%02d", minutesTextOut, secondsTextOut)
    endTime.text = strDuration



}

@IBAction func sliderSong(_ sender: UISlider) {

        //перемотка аудиозвука
        let duration = CMTimeGetSeconds(avPlayer!.currentItem!.asset.duration)
        let value = sliderSong.value
        let durationToSeek = Float(duration) * value

        avPlayer?.seek(to: CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(Float64(durationToSeek),avPlayer!.currentItem!.duration.timescale)) { [](state) in

            if (self.iconChange.currentImage?.isEqual(UIImage(named: "Play.png")))! {
                self.avPlayer?.pause()
            } else if (self.iconChange.currentImage?.isEqual(UIImage(named: "Pause.png")))!{
                self.avPlayer?.play()
            }
        }
}


@IBAction func volume(_ sender: UISlider) {

    avPlayer?.volume = sender.value
}



@IBAction func minusThirtySec(_ sender: Any) {

    let playerCurrentTime = CMTimeGetSeconds((avPlayer?.currentTime())!)
    var newTime = playerCurrentTime - seekDurationThirty

    if newTime < 0 {
        newTime = 0
    }
    let time2: CMTime = CMTimeMake(Int64(newTime * 1000 as Float64), 1000)
    avPlayer?.seek(to: time2, toleranceBefore: kCMTimeZero, toleranceAfter: kCMTimeZero)


}
@IBAction func minusTenSec(_ sender: Any) {

    let playerCurrentTime = CMTimeGetSeconds((avPlayer?.currentTime())!)
    var newTime = playerCurrentTime - seekDuration

    if newTime < 0 {
        newTime = 0
    }
    let time2: CMTime = CMTimeMake(Int64(newTime * 1000 as Float64), 1000)
    avPlayer?.seek(to: time2, toleranceBefore: kCMTimeZero, toleranceAfter: kCMTimeZero)

}

@IBAction func plusTenSec(_ sender: Any) {

    guard let duration = avPlayer?.currentItem?.duration else{
        return
    }
    let playerCurrentTime = CMTimeGetSeconds((avPlayer?.currentTime())!)
    let newTime = playerCurrentTime + seekDuration

    if newTime < (CMTimeGetSeconds(duration) - seekDuration) {

        let time2: CMTime = CMTimeMake(Int64(newTime * 1000 as Float64), 1000)
        avPlayer?.seek(to: time2, toleranceBefore: kCMTimeZero, toleranceAfter: kCMTimeZero)

    }

}
@IBAction func plusThirtySec(_ sender: Any) {

    guard let duration = avPlayer?.currentItem?.duration else{
        return
    }
    let playerCurrentTime = CMTimeGetSeconds((avPlayer?.currentTime())!)
    let newTime = playerCurrentTime + seekDurationThirty

    if newTime < (CMTimeGetSeconds(duration) - seekDuration) {

        let time2: CMTime = CMTimeMake(Int64(newTime * 1000 as Float64), 1000)
        avPlayer?.seek(to: time2, toleranceBefore: kCMTimeZero, toleranceAfter: kCMTimeZero)

    }

}

@IBAction func Next(_ sender: Any) {

    let url = URL(string: mod[thisSong].UrlName!)
    let playerItem = AVPlayerItem(url: url!)
    avPlayer = AVQueuePlayer(playerItem:playerItem)

    avPlayer?.insert(playerItem, after: playerItem)
    avPlayer?.advanceToNextItem()


 //        if thisSong + 1 > mod.count {
 //            thisSong = 0
 //        } else {
 //            thisSong += 1
  //        }
  //      
  //        
  //        if thisSong != mod.count{
  //            
 //            name.text = mod[thisSong].AudioName
 //            player(urlSong:mod[thisSong].UrlName!)
 //            avPlayer?.play()
 //
 //            
 //            
 //        }

}
@IBAction func Back(_ sender: Any) {



 //        if thisSong != 0{
 //            thisSong -= 1
 //            name.text = mod[thisSong].AudioName
 //            player(urlSong:mod[thisSong].UrlName!)
 //            avPlayer?.play()
 //
 //            
 //        }

}




@IBAction func Play(_ sender: Any) {


    if avPlayer?.rate == 0 {
        avPlayer?.play()
        avPlayer?.rate = 1.0
        iconChange.setImage(UIImage(named:"Pause.png"), for: .normal)


        avPlayer?.addPeriodicTimeObserver(forInterval: CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(1, 1), queue: nil, using: {
            (CMTime) -> Void in

            self.updateProgressBar()
        })



    } else {
        avPlayer?.rate = 0.0
        avPlayer?.pause()
        iconChange.setImage(UIImage(named:"Play.png"), for: .normal)

    }

}


func player(urlSong:String) {




}



func updateProgressBar(){
    let timeNow = Int(avPlayer!.currentTime().value) / Int(avPlayer!.currentTime().timescale)

    let minutesText = timeNow / 60
    let secondsText = timeNow % 60

    let duration = String(format:"%02d:%02d", minutesText, secondsText)
    startTime.text = duration

}
```

And `tableview` from here I get the data

```
var thisSong = 0


 class TableViewControllerAudioList: UITableViewController {


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 50
    tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension



}

override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
    return 1
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
    return modalsF.count
}


override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! TableViewCellAudioList

    cell.name.text = modalsF[indexPath.row].AudioName
    cell.number.text = "\(indexPath.row + 1)"

    thisSong = indexPath.row


    return cell
}



override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    let vc  = segue.destination as? ViewControllerAudioDetail

    vc?.mod = [modalsF[(tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow?.row)!]]

}
```

Comment: I have added my answer please add that methods in your code it will work definitely. if have want i have whole example of it.

Comment: @AshokLondhe I already solved this problem but your method is also working

Comment: You are right. both are working but i would like to suggest go with my answer because that is optimized code. also its very easy to understand. if have any such problem in AVPlayer let me know i will definitely help you. Thanks.

Comment: @AshokLondhe Can you helmp me with this problem?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44921042/avplayer-is-created-2-times

Comment: Sure i would like to help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Play the selected / current song**

```
func play(at index: Int) {
    audioPlayer.removeAllItems()
    playerItem = audioItems[index]
    playerItem?.seek(to: kCMTimeZero)
    audioPlayer.insert(playerItem!, after: nil)
    audioPlayer.play()
    isPlaying = true

    self.playAllSongsTableView.reloadData()
}
```

**To play previuos song....**

```
@IBAction func backWordAction(_ sender: UIButton) {
   var index =  audioItems.index(of: audioPlayer.currentItem!) ?? 0
    if index > 0 {
        index = index - 1
    }
    play(at: index)
}
```

**To play next song....**

```
@IBAction func forwordAction(_ sender: UIButton) {
    var index =  audioItems.index(of: audioPlayer.currentItem!) ?? 0
    if index < (audioItems.count - 1) {
        index = index + 1
    }
    play(at: index)

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Using AVQueuePlayer instead of AVPlayer will let you directly add items;

```
AVQueuePlayer.insert(item: AVPlayerItem, after: AVPlayerItem?)
AVQueuePlayer.advanceToNextItem()
```

You can also initialize the player with an array of AVPlayerItems

```
AVQueuePlayer = AVQueuePlayer(items: [AVPlayerItem])
```

Answer (score 1):

In its `tableview` I added `func didSelectRowAt` in which I wrote a global counter that received the cell number

```
 override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    thisSong = indexPath.row

}
```

And pass the data to the controller through `prepareForSegue`

```
 override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

    if segue.identifier ==  "listToDetail"{
        let vc  = segue.destination as? ViewControllerAudioDetail
        vc?.mod = mod
    }
}
```

In my detailed controller I created two buttons for the previous song and the next one

```
var avPlayer:AVPlayer?

var mod = [Modal]()


@IBAction func Next(_ sender: Any) {


    if thisSong == mod.count - 1 {
        thisSong = 0
    } else {
        thisSong += 1
    }


    if thisSong != mod.count{
        avPlayer?.removeTimeObserver(sliderDuration)

        name.text = mod[thisSong].AudioName
        player(urlSong:mod[thisSong].UrlName!)

        Status()

    }

}

@IBAction func Back(_ sender: Any) {


    if thisSong != 0 {
        thisSong -= 1
    } else {
        thisSong = mod.endIndex
    }


        avPlayer?.removeTimeObserver(sliderDuration)
        name.text = mod[thisSong].AudioName
        player(urlSong:mod[thisSong].UrlName!)

       Status()




}
```

And the function determines which was the status of the player and sets the same data

```
func Status(){
    if status == true {
        iconChange.setImage(UIImage(named:"Pause.png"), for: .normal)
        avPlayer?.play()
    } else {
        iconChange.setImage(UIImage(named:"Play.png"), for: .normal)
        avPlayer?.pause()
    }

}
```

Here I create a player

```
func player(urlSong:String) {

    let url = URL(string: urlSong)
    let playerItem = AVPlayerItem(url: url!)
    avPlayer = AVPlayer(playerItem:playerItem)


     sliderDuration = avPlayer!.addPeriodicTimeObserver(forInterval: CMTime(seconds: 1, preferredTimescale: CMTimeScale(NSEC_PER_SEC)), queue: DispatchQueue.main) { [weak self] (time) in

        let duration = CMTimeGetSeconds((self?.avPlayer!.currentItem!.asset.duration)!)
        self?.sliderSong.value = Float(CMTimeGetSeconds(time)) / Float(duration)

    }


    let duration = CMTimeGetSeconds(avPlayer!.currentItem!.asset.duration)
    let minutesTextOut = Int(duration) / 60 % 60
    let secondsTextOut = Int(duration) % 60
    let strDuration = String(format:"%02d:%02d", minutesTextOut, secondsTextOut)
    endTime.text = strDuration


}
```